# Heroku log CPU load not displayed

Tags: java, performance, git, heroku, cpu-usage

I measure load CPU on heroku via Git Bash by command `heroku logs --app dip-app-2`. When my JAVA application don't get any request, I get output which consists of this records:

[image]

But when I start JMeter generate requests on my application, I get output consist of this records:

[image]

Because log don't contain records with CPU load statistic when JMeter charge this app? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could go for simply installing a Heroku addon designed for application performance monitoring. You can find a list of such addons in the **Analytics** section [here](https://addons.heroku.com/).

I would personally use [New Relic](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic) for performance monitoring and resource usage. Just call ***heroku addons:add newrelic*** in your command line and it installs automatically.